# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'

Tags: angular

I have seen pretty many answers and i think I have followed every advise given but for the life of me, I cant figure out whats missing. I have imported CommonModule to my module and exported the component but still nothing.

I have a second module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { EmployeedbComponent } from './employeedb.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [EmployeedbComponent],
  declarations: [EmployeedbComponent]
})
export class EmployeedbModule { }
```

my component just have one array called items.

my html is:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">


         </tr>
```

Comment: can you show your webpack.config.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add BrowserModule to imports: [] in **`@NgModule()`** , The **`BrowserModule`** should be imported in the app module, in other modules **`CommonModule`** should be imported

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule]
  ..
})
```

Comment: I have BrowserModule in my main module (app.module.ts) already. And the documentation states it should be loaded only in one location while common module in other modules as necessary

Comment: in that case its not an issue with the import, can you restart your app and inspect in your browser, whether modules have been loaded correctly

Comment: what is the version of angular

Comment: I imported it then removed it...just to try my luck. It is version 4.

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan. I located the problem! I had nested components and I had to include it in the parent module as well.

Comment: That is what mentioned in the comment! glad you resolved it. revoke the downvote if you have done so

Comment: I didn't downvote, i guess but removed it. Thanks a lot.